# PHP form Loop Variables

Tags: php, email, variables, loops

I am working on a PHP form that allows a user to add rows to a table and then submit the information using the form through email. I need to pass the variables into the email. I have tried using this:

```
$n = count($type);
$i = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    $e_classes = "______________________________________________ \r\n\n";
    $e_classes .=  "Class Type: {$type[$i]} \r\n";
    $e_classes .= "Number of Classes: {$nc[$i]} \r\n";
    $e_classes .= "Number of Students: {$sc[$i]} \r\n";
    $e_classes .= "______________________________________________ \r\n\n";
}
```

But when I get the email only the last one in the table is displaying. How would I get all of the added table rows to display? I can make everything work if I use 'echo', but I need to pass everything into a variable that I can use for an email.

Comment: Change the first instance of `$e_classes = "` to `$e_classes .= "`

Comment: Every time you enter that `for` loop you override your `$e_classes` variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this :

```
$e_classes = '';
$n = count($type);
$i = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    $e_classes .= "______________________________________________ \r\n\n";
    $e_classes .=  "Class Type: {$type[$i]} \r\n";
    $e_classes .= "Number of Classes: {$nc[$i]} \r\n";
    $e_classes .= "Number of Students: {$sc[$i]} \r\n";
    $e_classes .= "______________________________________________ \r\n\n";
}
```

Your first entry in your loop for the variable `$e_classes` was erasing what she had before because you used `$e_classes =` instead of `$e_classes .=`.

This mean before each loop, your variable was reset with the value of your first row.

You were doing this :

```
$Var = '';
for($i = 0, $i < n; $i++){
    $Var = 'a';
}

// Loop 1
$Var = 'a';

// Loop 2
$Var = 'a';

// Loop 3
$Var = 'a';
```

You wanted this :

```
$Var = '';
for($i = 0, $i < n; $i++){
    $Var .= 'a';
}

// Loop 1
$Var = 'a';

// Loop 2
$Var = 'aa';

// Loop 3
$Var = 'aaa';
```

The symbol `=` will overwrite the variable's value with the new one.

The symbol `.=` will append the value at the end of the variable.

Comment: FREAKIN BRILLIANT! Thanks so much for the help, worked perfectly!!

Comment: @blutick Your welcome. Just mark as answered the question please. Thanks.